# Autotest-4.4.6/ZenTest-4.4.1 broken with Rspec2 and Rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, autotest, zentest

ZenTest and Autotest have been updated on December 1st. After upgrading to the latest versions (Autotest-4.4.6/ZenTest-4.4.1), autotest won't discover my specs and tries to run the standard unit test. The output of autotest is as follow : 
`xto@Cygnus:~/projects/ruby/hibou$ autotest
(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.)
/home/xto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/test_helper.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u`

Downgarding to Autotest-4.4.5/ZenTest-4.4.0 fixes the problem...

Any tips would be appreciated...

Comment: Forgot to mention i'm using Ruby 1.9.2p0

Answer (score 4):

Run it via 'autotest -s rspec2' (With the latest autotest and zentest)

Comment: This worked for me. ZenTest 4.4.1 (autotest is now a deprecated gem) on Ruby 1.9.2-p0

Comment: That's great! I'll give a try tonight then :D

Comment: Thanks, saved me half an hour searching for this solution

Answer (score 0):

Did u try running autotest with RSPEC=true ? something like this RSPEC=true autotest

Comment: Just tried it and unfortunately, the output is the same :


xto@Phoenix:~/projects/ruby/hibou$ autotest RSPEC=true
(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.)
/home/xto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/test_helper.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
Loaded suite -e
Started

Finished in 0.002613 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


Test run options: --seed 49902

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded ZenTest to 4.4.2 and autotest works without specifying any arguments on the CLI.

Comment: ZenTest 4.5.0 and i had to use autotest -s rspec2 to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You might not have a `.rspec` file in Rails.root so `autotest` does not know about your specs. You generate it by runnig: `rails generate rspec:install`.

And you need to have `gem 'autotest-rails` in the Gemfile (next to `gem 'ZenTest'`).

Here's the installation instruction: http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/file/autotest